# Crystal reports login prompt leaves database name blank when displaying report .net winform application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

We have developed a CRM C#.NET application in VS2015 (.net 4.5) where we display alot of reports.

Since a couple of months we have a problem with a login prompt that is displaying when generating the report, all fields are correctly filled in except the database which is blank and also disabled.

[image]

This problem only occurs after we made database changes to a report (when adding tables ect.)

In the report we use SQL native client 11.

The database connection is passed in the code:

First the report is beeing loaded.

Next we set the login info:

```
var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo
{
    ServerName = servername,
    DatabaseName = databasename,
    UserID = userid,
    Password = password,
};


var crTables = _report.Database.Tables;
foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
{
    var crtableLogoninfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);                 
}


_report.SetDatabaseLogon(userid, password);
_report.DataSourceConnections[0].IntegratedSecurity = false;
```

After that we set the reportsource and the parameterfields:

```
 _crView.ReportSource = _report;    
 _crParameterFields = _crView.ParameterFieldInfo;
```

Has anyone else also encountered this issue?

Tried different solutions like adding legacyV2 runtime to the app.config.

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by changing the datatype in the report from SQLNCLI11 TO SQLOLEDB